# App Force Close

Tags: java, android, onclick, forceclose

My app force closes on the onClick (goForIt). I'm just trying to set a content View but it forces closes eatch time I press my button. And also is it possible to make an app with only 1 activity ?
Could somebody tell me why please:

```
package com.XanderApps.techquizz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

     public void goForIt(View view) {
     setContentView(R.layout.question_one);

     }


    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.checkbox_meat:
                if (checked)
                    setContentView(R.layout.choice_done);






                break;
            case R.id.checkbox_cheese:
                if (checked)
                    System.exit(0);


                break;

        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post a logcat stack trace please

Comment: Thanks but I just can't use my emulator :/

Comment: @user2670035 without a logcat of the error it will be hard to help

Comment: Well i'll try to run the emulator again thanks

Comment: You can use logcat even if you are running on an actual device.

Comment: Use fragments in a single activity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at your Logcat, my guess is that you are getting a 'NullPointerException' when you try to access your button.

Make sure you are 'instantiating' your button object using the findViewById syntax, before you are trying to use onClick().

Comment: Il try that as soon as possible

Comment: Glad you got your issue fixed.  Not instantiating resources is a common error.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't instantiated your <kbd>goForIt</kbd> inside `onCreateView()` of `Activity`. Thus it throws *NPE(Null Pointer Exception)*.

Get your `id` of <kbd>goForIt</kbd> from your `XML` layout file.

Add

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 goForit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.goForItId);
 }
```

And then add `onClickListener` on <kbd>goForIt</kbd>.

Comment: Yes that's what I just did i'll try to run it now thanks alot